# UNIX SHELL SCRIPT - MYSQL issue

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

Below Unix shell script fails saying unexpected end of file at the mysql  line before $selectg line.  Not sure what mistake i am doing.  Provided part of script below.  Could anyone help me out.

```
    #!/bin/bash
  ip="77.299.113.81" 
  pass="-ptest123"

        read -d '' selectg <<EOGG   SELECT * FROM agstatus ; EOGG

        for row in `mysql  -h $ip -u root $pass "ruttt" -e "SELECT  databasename FROM master.customers"`; do
           rownum=$((rownum+1))
           echo "Row:$row"
        if [ $rownum -ne 1 ]; then
        mysql -u tsadm -p'test123' -h 77.299.113.81 Csfgat  << eof
        $selectg
        eof
        fi
        done
        echo "done"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end token of a here document has to be on a line by itself:

```
read -d '' selectg <<EOGG
SELECT * FROM agstatus;
EOGG
```

Alternatively, you can use a here string:

```
read -d '' selectg <<< "SELECT * FROM agstatus;"
```

Or in your specific case, a plain ol' assignment:

```
selectg="SELECT * FROM agstatus;"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and info.    Problem was I had Tab after EOF.  Deleted the tab and it worked.